# UWP Bluetooth Device Connect No more data is available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070103)

Tags: bluetooth, win-universal-app

I have the following line of code,

await _socket.ConnectAsync(_service.ConnectionHostName, _service.ConnectionServiceName);

The device is on I can get the Device Info but when I connect I get an exception

"No more data is available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070103)"

I cant find any real answer to this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me the solution was to remove the device from paired devices and then pair it again.

Comment: I will try it out